# Can multiple users access/update a single Android app in the Market?

Tags: android, permissions, apk, google-play

I'm trying to give someone else at my office access to the download statistics for our app in the Market, but there seems to be no way to permission it (like in Flurry, et al). Anyone know a way to give others access?

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, no, only one Google account can access the market.  I think that somewhere it says they're working on adding the multi-user feature.

As a workaround, my team created a new Google account which we share the password of. After creating a new account you can assign ownership of all the existing marketplace apps to the new account via a support request.

Here's a support forum thread discussing it:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=327297c08485a353&hl=en